# WebBrowser not firing event DocumentCompleted

Tags: c#, .net

So I've written a piece of code inside a console application that just simply makes a web browser from `System.Windows.Forms` visit a website. Now the proble I'm facing is, the `DocumentCompleted` event will not fire if I use a ready made WebBrowser, as you can see I pass one into the constructor.

My ideal way would be to use the WebBrowser passed in via the constructor, and just navigate on the same WebBrowser, for some reason, it wont fire the `DocumentCompleted` event when using the same browser, it forces me to initialize a new browser, inside a new thread every time.

Why is this?

Here is the code that works, but has to initialize a new browser every time.

```
public class WebController
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger = new ConsoleLogger(typeof(WebController));

    private WebBrowser _webBrowser;
    private readonly string _webAddress;

    private bool _sendingMessage;
    private string _lastMessage;

    public WebController(WebBrowser webBrowser)
    {
        _webAddress = "https://{username}.example.com/";
    }

    public void SendMessage(string username, string message)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            _webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
            _webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += BrowserDocumentCompleted;
            _webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            _webBrowser.Navigate(_webAddress);
            Application.Run();
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void BrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser)?.Url.AbsolutePath)
        {
            return;
        }

        _logger.Warn("Navigated to: " + e.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not need a thread at all

Comment: If I remove the code outside of its own thread, the `BrowserDocumentCompleted` event will not fire

Comment: why does your constructor have a `WebBrowser webBrowser`, can you update it?

Comment: @Dongdong he does if he doesn't want to lock the UI thread

Comment: Is there a reason your using `Thread` and not `Task`? There is pretty much no good reason to use `Thread` anymore. `Task` has better...well everything

Comment: There is a lot of weird stuff going on here. why do you pass `WebBrowser webBrowser` into the constructor and do nothing with it? Why do you store this in the class if it's only referenced inside the thread? Why are you using a windows forms component inside a console app? I kinda get the feeling your trying to run before you can crawl here.

Comment: WebBrowser is the kind of control that is strongly aware of on what thread it was created.  It is only capable of firing events when that thread is STA and executes a dispatcher loop (aka Application.Run).  We can't tell from the snippet what kind of thread calls the WebController constructor, but we can tell that it is the wrong kind.  You already know what the right kind looks like from your SendMessage() method.

Comment: this code will save you: https://github.com/r-aghaei/WebScraperExample/blob/master/src/WebScraper/BrowserBasedWebScraper.cs